# Memcached lru_crawler metadump doesn't returns END as response

Tags: memcached, dump

We are currently working on getting all the keys in Memcached through:

```
lru_crawler metadump all
```

For this implementation, we are expecting `END` or `OK` at the end of result.

But Memcached doesn't return any response code after the end of data. It just simply returns the metadata.

```
lru_crawler metadump 1
key=key exp=-1 la=1588598718 cas=1 fetch=no cls=1 size=80
```

We are using Memcached version **1.4.33**.

Is there any configuration that we need to set up for this to return a response code at the end (or) Is there any way that we can find the end of **metadump** result other than END or OK?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is a known issue with the Memcahed

https://github.com/memcached/memcached/issues/667

Answer (score 0):

(came across this post when researching a project I'm working on)

It is no longer an issue in current memcache implementations - I'm using 1.5.6 and get 'END'. However it is my experience that this does not always return the full list. I suspect that may be due the order of items in the LRU list changing while command is running (I get 99-100% of the keys when the server is getting hammered).